# using cut on a result of running another bash script

Tags: bash, cut

I want to run script score with "A" and "B" parameters and apply cut on the result. In the following way:

```
targetTeamOffence=`sh ./score.sh A B | cut d" " -f2`
```

However I'm getting wrong usage of cut error.

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `-` with `-d`:

```
targetTeamOffence=`sh ./score.sh A B | cut -d" " -f2`
```

Comment: Oh my god, this is embarrassing.
Thanks! [I'll accept this answer as soon as I can]